# Object detection from webcam using roboflow

Tags: python, python-requests, roboflow

Im trying to make a object detection program using my webcam but cant get it to work

This is my code

```
import cv2 as cv
import base64
import numpy as np
import requests

ROBOFLOW_API_KEY = "*********"
ROBOFLOW_MODEL = "chess-full-ddsxf"  # eg xx-xxxx--#
ROBOFLOW_SIZE = 416

upload_url = "".join([
    "https://detect.roboflow.com/",
    ROBOFLOW_MODEL,
    "?access_token=",
    ROBOFLOW_API_KEY,
    "&format=image",
    "&stroke=5"
])

video = cv.VideoCapture(1)

# Check if camera opened successfully
if (video.isOpened()):
    print("successfully opening video stream or file")


# Infer via the Roboflow Infer API and return the result
def infer():
    # Get the current image from the webcam
    ret, frame = video.read()

    # Resize (while maintaining the aspect ratio)
    # to improve speed and save bandwidth
    height, width, channels = frame.shape
    scale = ROBOFLOW_SIZE / max(height, width)
    img = cv.resize(frame, (round(scale * width), round(scale * height)))

    # Encode image to base64 string
    retval, buffer = cv.imencode('.jpg', img)
    img_str = base64.b64encode(buffer)

    # Get prediction from Roboflow Infer API
    resp = requests.post(upload_url, data=img_str, headers={
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }, stream=True).raw

    # Parse result image
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv.imdecode(image, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)

    return image


# Main loop; infers sequentially until you press "q"
while video.isOpened():
    # On "q" keypress, exit
    key = cv.waitKey(5)
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

    # Synchronously get a prediction from the Roboflow Infer API
    image = infer()
    # And display the inference results
    cv.imshow('image', image)

# Release resources when finished
video.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Error message:**
successfully opening video stream or file

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Atom\testingCode\webcamRoboflow\infer.py", line 64, in  cv.imshow('image', image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:967: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

[Finished in 22.357s]

Comment: what does `resp.read()` return, exactly ? it's for sure not a decoded numpy array, but either txt (an error) or an image you need to imdecode() first

Comment: To be honest i dont know. Im trying to follow this tutorial from Roboflow: https://blog.roboflow.com/python-webcam/

Comment: try to print out the first 20 bytes or so

Comment: i dont know how to do that, sorry

Comment: x=resp.read(); `print(x)`

Comment: Okey this is what i got: b''

Comment: Try putting that print right before the `# Parse result image`

Comment: Okey got some new error messages now:   Webcam is OK
b'{"message":"Not Found"}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Atom\testingCode\webcamRoboflow\infer.py", line 64, in <module>
    image = infer()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Atom\testingCode\webcamRoboflow\infer.py", line 51, in infer
    image = cv.imdecode(image, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:816: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !buf.empty() in function 'cv::imdecode_'

[Finished in 21.87s]

Comment: Are you sure your webcam device is “1”? Usually it’s “0”

Comment: I am sure. I did try 0, 2 and 3 now without any change

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to include the version of your model that you want to infer against so you're hitting an endpoint that isn't defined on the server.

```
ROBOFLOW_MODEL = "chess-full-ddsxf"  # eg xx-xxxx--#
```

This should be eg

```
ROBOFLOW_MODEL = "chess-full-ddsxf/1"  # eg xx-xxxx--#
```

If you trained your model on the first generated version of your dataset.